# Leitura de Arquivo Binário em C++

Tags: c++, arquivo, struct, stream-de-arquivos

Bom dia.

Estou tentando fazer uma leitura de structs que eu inseri em um arquivo binário, mas está dando erro na hora da leitura.

Segue o código da função de leitura:

```
void lerRegistros(char* file_name)
{
    ifstream entrada;
    entrada.open(file_name, ios::binary);

    if ( entrada )
    {
        entrada.seekg(0, entrada.end);
        int tam = entrada.tellg();
        entrada.seekg(0, entrada.beg);

        int numero_registros = tam / sizeof(registro);

        registro* vetor_registros = new registro[numero_registros];

        for (int i = 0; i < numero_registros; i++) 
        {
            entrada.read((char*)(&vetor_registros[i]), sizeof(registro));         
        }

        entrada.close();

        for ( int i = 0; i < numero_registros; ++i )
        {   
            cout << "Nome da banda: " << vetor_registros[i].nome << endl;
            cout << "Numero de integrantes: " << vetor_registros[i].numero_integrantes << endl;
            cout << "Estilo: " << vetor_registros[i].estilo << endl;
            cout << "Ano de criacao: " << vetor_registros[i].ano_criacao << endl;
            cout << "Melhor hit: " << vetor_registros[i].musica_famosa << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }

        vetor_registros = NULL;
        delete[] vetor_registros;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Erro na leitura do arquivo!";
    }

    return;
}
```

No programa, eu peço o nome do arquivo para ler os registros e passo esse nome para a função de leitura. O mais estranho é que se eu rodar o programa sem fechar ele, a leitura é feita normalmente após cada inserção de um novo registro. Mas se eu fechar o programa e abrir ele de novo, e tentar ler do mesmo arquivo que já foi criado aí dá erro na leitura e o programa fecha na hora. Se alguém souber o que pode ser, eu agradeço.

Segue a definição da estrutura:

```
struct banda_rock 
{
    string nome;
    int numero_integrantes;
    string estilo;
    int ano_criacao;
    string musica_famosa;
};
```

E segue abaixo o código que faz a escrita no arquivo e chama a função "lerRegistros". Na função "lerRegistros", eu coloquei um vetor de "registro", mas foi só para simplificar o código, na verdade é um vetor de "banda_rock", que é o nome do tipo struct que eu criei.

```
int quant = 0;
char* file_name;

banda_rock* ptrcatalogo;

cout << endl << "Digite a quantidade de bandas : ";
cin >> quant;

file_name = new char[100];

cout << "Digite o nome do arquivo a ser armazenado as bandas (com o extensao) : ";
cin >> file_name;
cin.ignore();

ptrcatalogo = new banda_rock[quant];

ofstream salvar_bandas; 
salvar_bandas.open(file_name, ios::binary|ios::app);

inserir_cadastro(quant, ptrcatalogo);

for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++) 
{
    salvar_bandas.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&ptrcatalogo[i]), sizeof(banda_rock));                 
}

ptrcatalogo = NULL;
delete[] ptrcatalogo;

salvar_bandas.close();

lerRegistros(file_name);

file_name = NULL;
delete file_name;
```

Comment: Dá erro na leitura e executa o cout "Erro na leitura do arquivo"? Pode não ter nada a ver mas já pensou em trocar o if(entrada) por if(entrada.good()) ? Eu geralmente testo dessa forma.

Comment: Ele nem chega a exibir o cout "Erro na leitura do arquivo". A execução do programa encerra antes, ele mostra o texto "Nome da banda: " e aí dá o erro. Vou testar com essa condição no if que vc falou. Valeu!

Comment: Coloque também a definição da estrutura/classe `registro` assim como um exemplo do arquivo que está a tentar ler, para que seja fácil de reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Agora que reparei! Você está lendo o bloco direto na estrutura, alias, é uma estrutura ou uma classe? Como está a definição dela? Já adianto que, se o campo "nome" for string é certo que vai dar problema. (-:

Comment: Isso, é uma estrutura mesmo. O campo "nome" é uma string e tem outros dois campos na estrutura que são string. Não entendi porque dá problema se for string xD. Vou postar a definição da estrutura e o código que escreve no arquivo.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta colocando o que vocês pediram. Se puderem dar uma olhada, agradeço muito.

Comment: @MuriloAugustoTeixeiraBiagi na escrita você está convertendo de um struct direto para um ponteiro de char, provavelmente o arquivo já está gravando corrompido.

Comment: O problema é que a função write recebe como primeiro argumento um char*, então eu preciso fazer um cast pra char* da minha struct na hora da gravação.

Answer (score 1):

**Nota:**

Eu escrevi um código com base no que você tinha falado, que queria que o código fizesse. para demonstrar melhor a resposta, em termos da funcionalidades de C++.

**Detalhes:**

Você disse que está programando em **C++** mas está usando um estilo parecido com **C** não que seja errado, mas, por exemplo, não ha necessidade de usar naked pointers para manipular a struct que você criou, ou passar um const char* para a função de leitura, mas isso não vem ao caso da pergunta, o que eu quis te dizer com isso é para você estudar as "funcionalidades" que a linguagem te oferece, ao invés  de tentar fazer da maneira antiga.

**Resposta:**

Eu acredito que no seu código o que está errado na função de leitura, é o uso de read da forma que você usou,

> entrada.read((char*)(&vetor_registros[i]), sizeof(registro));

E também após o loop for em que você exibe os dados, você está definindo vetor_registros como NULL antes de deleta-lo:

> vetor_registros = NULL;
>   delete[] vetor_registros;

onde o certo seria:

> delete [] vetor_registros;
>   vetor_registros = nullptr;

**Código:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct banda_rock 
{
    std::string nome;
    int numero_integrantes;
    std::string estilo;
    int ano_criacao;
    std::string musica_famosa;
};

bool write( const std::string& file_name, const std::vector<banda_rock>& v_registers ); 
std::vector< banda_rock > read( const std::string& file_name );
void insert( const size_t& num_registers, std::vector<banda_rock>& v_registers );

int main()
{ 
    //quant deve ser size_t por que já que você tem a intenção de expressar a
    //quantidade de algo, e essa quantidade não pode ser negativa
    //(size_t só aceita valores positivos e o 0( no seu caso você não precisa do 0) )
    size_t quant = 0;
    std::string file_name;
    std::vector< banda_rock > v_catalogo;


    //Caso o que a pessoa digite não seja um número ou um numero menor que zero
    if( quant == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "\nDigite a quantidade de bandas : ";
        std::cin >> quant; 
        while( std::cin.fail() )
        { 
            std::cin.clear( std::ios::goodbit );
            std::cin.ignore(); 
            std::cin >> quant; 

        }
    }
    if( quant > 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "Digite o nome do arquivo a ser armazenado as bandas (com a extensao) : ";
        std::cin >> file_name; 
        while( std::cin.fail() )
        { 
            std::cin.clear( std::ios::goodbit );
            std::cin.ignore(); 
            std::cin >> file_name;
        }
    }       


    //chama a função que vai popular o vetor
    insert( quant, v_catalogo );

    //escreve  arquivo
    if( write( file_name, v_catalogo ) )
    {
        //se a operação de escrita obteve sucesso
        v_catalogo.clear();
        v_catalogo.shrink_to_fit();
        v_catalogo = read( file_name );
    }
    else{ std::cout << "\nNão foi possivel escrever no arquivo." << std::endl; }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < v_catalogo.size(); i++) 
    {
        std::cout << "\tNome: " << v_catalogo[ i ].nome << '\n' 
                  << "\tIntegrantes: " << v_catalogo[ i ].numero_integrantes << '\n' 
                  << "\tEstilo: " << v_catalogo[ i ].estilo << '\n'
                  << "\tAno de criação: " << v_catalogo[ i ].ano_criacao << '\n'
                  << "\tMúsica Famosa: " << v_catalogo[ i ].musica_famosa << "\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

bool write( const std::string& file_name, const std::vector<banda_rock>& v_registers )
{
    if( v_registers.empty() ){ return false; }

    std::ofstream out; 
    out.open( file_name, std::ios::binary|std::ios::app );
    if( !out.is_open() ){ out.close(); return false; }
    else
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < v_registers.size(); i++) 
        {
            //o # pode servir para posteriormente para você contar quantos 
            //registros você têm (fica a seu critério usá-lo ou não)
            out << '#' << ' ' 
                << v_registers[ i ].nome << ' ' 
                << v_registers[ i ].numero_integrantes << ' ' 
                << v_registers[ i ].estilo << ' '
                << v_registers[ i ].ano_criacao << ' '
                << v_registers[ i ].musica_famosa << '\n';            
        }
    }

    out.close();
    return true;
}

std::vector< banda_rock > read( const std::string& file_name )
{
    std::ifstream in;
    size_t quant = 0;
    char ch_aux;

    in.open(file_name, std::ios::binary);
    if ( !in.is_open() ){ in.close(); }
    else
    {
        while( !in.eof() )
        {
            in.get( ch_aux );
            if( ch_aux == '#' ){ quant++; }
        }
    }    
    in.close();

    std::vector<banda_rock> v_registers;
    v_registers.resize( quant );

    in.open(file_name, std::ios::binary);
    if ( !in.is_open() ){ in.close(); }
    else
    {
        for( size_t i = 0; i < v_registers.size(); i++ )
        {
                in.ignore( 1, '#' );
                in >> v_registers[ i ].nome 
                   >> v_registers[ i ].numero_integrantes
                   >> v_registers[ i ].estilo
                   >> v_registers[ i ].ano_criacao
                   >> v_registers[ i ].musica_famosa;
        } 
    }    
    in.close();

    return v_registers;

}

void insert( const size_t& num_registers, std::vector<banda_rock>& v_registers )
{
    v_registers.resize( num_registers );

    std::cout << "insira os dados da banda:" << std::endl;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < v_registers.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << " Nome da banda [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].nome;
        while( std::cin.fail() )
        { 
            std::cout << "\tpor favor digite o nome da banda [" << i + 1 << "]." << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear( std::ios::goodbit ); 
            std::cin.ignore();  
            std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].nome;
        }

        std::cout << " Número de integrantes da banda [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].numero_integrantes;
        while( std::cin.fail() )
        { 
            std::cout << "\tpor favor digite o número de integrantes da banda [" << i + 1 << "]." << std::endl; 
            std::cin.clear( std::ios::goodbit ); 
            std::cin.ignore(); 
            std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].numero_integrantes;
        }

        std::cout << " Estilo da banda [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].estilo;
        while( std::cin.fail() )
        { 
            std::cout << "\tpor favor digite o estilo da banda [" << i + 1 << "].";                                     
            std::cin.clear( std::ios::goodbit ); 
            std::cin.ignore();
            std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].estilo;
        }

        std::cout << " Ano de criação da banda [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].ano_criacao;
        while( std::cin.fail() )
        { 
            std::cout << "\tpor favor digite o ano de criação da banda [" << i + 1 << "]."; 
            std::cin.clear( std::ios::goodbit ); 
            std::cin.ignore(); 
            std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].ano_criacao;
        }

        std::cout << " Musica Conhecida da banda[" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].musica_famosa;
        while( std::cin.fail() )
        { 
            std::cout << "\tpor favor digite uma música conhecida da banda [" << i + 1 << "].";
            std::cin.clear( std::ios::goodbit );  
            std::cin.ignore(); 
            std::cin >> v_registers[ i ].musica_famosa;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! As dicas foram bem úteis e usei seu código como base para corrigir o meu. Essa forma de leitura no arquivo com o ">>" é bem mais prático do que usar a função "read". E alterei a forma de desalocar a memória dos ponteiros, realmente estava errado.

O programa agora funciona se as strings tiverem uma única palavra. Se eu colocar um nome de banda composto por exemplo, na hora da leitura ele só traz o primeiro nome da banda, no campo dos integrantes ele traz 0, o ano ele traz correto e a música conhecida traz em branco.

O que será que está causando isso ?

Comment: Só mais um detalhe, o arquivo em que eu gravo e leio é binário (.dat)

Comment: sobre o formato do qrquivo creio que não mude muito, o que você comentou sobre ler só a primeira palavra da banda é porque você esta std::cin para leitura e ele lê dessa forma, sugiro que use std::getline(), da uma olhada nesse link para você entender melhor como funciona. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: Valeu!! com o getline() deu certo, agora foi.

Comment: não se esqueça que você ainda tem um problema para resolver que é a leitura dos dados que estão com nomes compostos para dentro da sua estrutura. Agora como sugestão, eu não acho que essa é a melhor maneira de fazer isso (claro isso fica a seu critério). Por exemplo, você poderia usar um banco de dados para isso, ou como uma solução mais rápida voce poderia usar um arquivo xml

Answer (score 0):

Você tem o seguinte problema: Em c++ os arquivos binários não aceitam variáveis dinâmicas como `string`s e `vector`. Você precisa fazer a leitura/escrita no arquivo como um vetor de `char`, para isso use a função `reinterpret_cast`:

```
arquivo.write(reinterpret_cast  <const char *> 
(&variavel),sizeof(tipo_dado_variavel))


arquivo.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&variavel),
sizeof(tipo_dado_variavel))
```

*O operador `>>` não funciona para streams binários, tem que ser `arquivo.read/write` mesmo.